# Unity WebGL check if Mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

How can i check if webgl is being played on mobile environment?
I did google some examples on this but none of them worked properly.
I tried Input.touchSupported, and #if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i've just found the best way to do this.

http://answers.unity.com/answers/1698985/view.html

it worked right away.

assets/plugins/webgl/MyPlugin.jslib

```
var MyPlugin = {
   IsMobile: function()
   {
      return UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile;
   }
};  
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MyPlugin);
```

in Unity

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
 private static extern bool IsMobile();

 public bool isMobile()
 {
     #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
         return IsMobile();
     #endif
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the solution presented by *dav0803*, I had to replace this:

> return UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile;

for this:

> return Module.SystemInfo.mobile;

to get to work in Unity 2020.3.30f1

Answer (score 1):

Enough with:

```
Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WebGLPlayer && Application.isMobilePlatform
```

Answer (score 0):

Application.isMobilePlatform

use this property to check whether WebGL build is running on mobile or pc